# html: text and createElement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, struts

i have difficulty understanding the below code snippet. I am trying to understand where the `value` attribute is assigned to, however i only see the `property` attribute.

```
 <html:text indexed="true" name="<%=(String)
 currentItr.next()%>" property="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>"/>
```

because i am slightly more familiar with HTML DOM, i was able to create the element i want using below:

```
    object<%=i%> = document.createElement('
<input type="text" name="<%=name%>' + '[' + 
sectionId + '].mySpecialList[' + row[id] + '].
<%=curProp%>" id=' + sectionId + 
'size="<%=curItr.next()%>" value="<%=curItr.next()%>">');
```

which i know i can grab and access using the following:

```
var obj = document.forms["myForm"].elements["mySpecialList[0].mySmallList[0].someProperty"];
```

what is the `html:struts` equivalent of the `createElement` bit? Because when i use the `html:text` code snippet, i am unable retrieve or parse the `value` attribute.

for example: the `<html:text>` tag seems to automatically create an element with name, value and size. however, when i try to access the same element in javascript, i get the element's column name instead, and not the value

Comment: Why not?  The value is populated from the bean property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unreadable and you should not use scriptlets, use JSTL for that.

```
<html:text property="propertyNameOfYourBean"/>
```

For list you should use `<c:forEach>` tag.